# Multiple block form in same back end magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, forms, adminform

I'm new to Magento. I've built some grid and Edit forms, but I don't know how to add multible edit block and tables in the same page.

**What I've built is something like this:**
[image]

**What I need is something like this:**
[image]

This is my edit Form.php

```
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form', array('legend' => 'Informations'));

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Name',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'name'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('city', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'City',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'city'
        ));

        if ($commerciauxData = Mage::registry('commerciaux_data')) {
            $form->setValues($commerciauxData->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another section with:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);

    // section one
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form', array('legend' => 'Informations'));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Name',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'name'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('city', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'City',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'city'
    ));

    // section two
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form_2', array('legend' => 'Informations'));

    $fieldset->addField('your_field', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Field Name',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'your_field'
    ));

    if ($commerciauxData = Mage::registry('commerciaux_data')) {
        $form->setValues($commerciauxData->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Comment: but that will add the field in the same form block not in a separate one I think, I've tried but I didn't receive any change.

Comment: Added full code ... You can use the methods you've already uses.

Comment: I'd like to add a grid(in the same form page) or table like this where and how I can implement this?